# Append to an array inside an object functional way

Tags: javascript, purely-functional

Let's say I have an object like

```
const team = {
  name: "something",
  members: [1, 2, 3],
};
```

and in the above object I want to append the value 4 to the array?

would this be acceptable code?

```
const newTeam = { ...team, members: team.members.concat(userId) };
```

I am using concat because it does not modify the array and I don't think I have to use map in this instance. Is my thinking, correct?

Comment: Yes. You could also use array spread: `members: [...team.members, userId]`

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you, for the confirmation!

Comment: The Q. itself, at least in JS, is a contradiction. *"Append to an  array"* implies (or pretty much sounds like) the mutation of exactly that array. And even though both approaches are straightforward and clean, I don't see anything *(purely) functional* related in it. The problem as well as the solution(s) pretty much read like ... *How reliable is spread syntax for cloning a certain (or this specific) object structure?*